# IPtables not forwarding user error

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, port-forwarding, iptables

So I am trying to forward traffic from the internal port 514 to the internal port 55514 over udp (running Ubuntu 19, syslog coming in on 514 from firewall, logstash listening on 55514) It's not happening though. I stripped down and flushed iptables:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
```

Disabled the firewall:

```
sudo ufw disable
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
```

IPtables status:

```
sudo iptables -L

  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination

  Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
  target     prot opt source               destination
```

Traffic is definitely coming in through port 514:

```
sudo tcpdump -u -i eno1 port 514

  tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
  listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
  13:04:49.898982 IP _gateway.syslog > elktest.syslog: SYSLOG user.warning, length: 70
  13:04:50.429960 IP _gateway.syslog > elktest.syslog: SYSLOG user.warning, length: 70
  13:04:50.961035 IP _gateway.syslog > elktest.syslog: SYSLOG user.warning, length: 70
  13:04:51.164793 IP _gateway.syslog > elktest.syslog: SYSLOG local0.info, length: 185
  13:04:51.491999 IP _gateway.syslog > elktest.syslog: SYSLOG user.warning, length: 70
```

I applied these rules:

```
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i eno1 -p udp -d 192.168.50.225 --dport 514 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD -i eno1 -p tcp -d 192.168.50.225 --dport 514 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eno1 -p udp --dport 514 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.50.225:55514
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 514 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.50.225:55514
```

And yet, when I listen to the desired port (55514):

```
sudo tcpdump -u -i eno1 port 55514

  tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
  listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
  **crickets**
```

I get absolutely nothing. Any advice, comments that you can give me are appreciated. Please help.

Comment: Your post is good, but it would be useful to add what systems) you are doing the dumps on - ie source, router or target in each case.

Comment: Is 192.168.50.225 the same machine? Check the loopback interface `sudo tcpdump -u -i lo port 55514`. I am not positive where you would intercept this traffic if it is the same machine because linux gets clever in taking shortcuts when a traffic's destination is local.

Comment: Sorry yes that (192.168.50.225) is the machine's local IP.

Comment: Thanks so much @davidgo and @Andy, it was working the whole time! `sudo tcpdump -u -i lo port 55514` did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried it, but I posit that the immediate problem is the tcpdump command - specifically the input is still coming in destined for 514 - not 55514 and this can't be changed on the router as its an input.

I would try monitoring both the input and output on 514 and 55514 and seeing the response.

Comment: How do I monitor the output of a port? Does tcpdump monitor the input or the output?

Comment: tcpdump appears to me to monitor the interface. What happens if you replace -i eno1 with -i any (ie so you are monitoring the input and output interface)

Comment: Okay a reboot later it's not forwarding anymore. I checked iptables and all the rules are still there... I don't know what's going on

Comment: That should probably be posted as anothwr question. Are the rules in the correctorder? Rules are interpreted from to to bottom, woth +I inserting at the top and -A appending to the bottom. Also, is ip_forwardimg set?

Comment: What is ip_forwarding? (if this doesn't fix it I'll make a new question)

Comment: (sorry, brief because answering from cellphone) There is a kernel setting like /proc/sys/net/????/ip_forward which needs to be set to forward packets between interfaces.

Comment: okay about to post new question, it seems that iptables only forwards sporadically... it may be that some types of packets are getting filtered out because my rules aren't broad enough, but idk

Comment: iptables -vnL will list the rules, along with the number of packets (first column) and bytes (second column) which might help work out which rules are being hit.  Its unlikely iptables is only forwarding sporadically, it may be a connection tracking thing though.